# Change thickness of complex object

Tags: sketchup

I have a complex object (A door) that I have created. I need to make it thicker but without changing the ratio of the profiles, etc, so i cant just use the scale tool. My door is a group with sub groups. If I could select faces and points from the middle out to one side I could then move them all until correct thickness is achieved. Dont know how to do that. Any tips?

[image]

Comment: Just to clarify, is your goal to maintain everything in proportion, or to maintain the surface contours while making the whole thing thicker?  For example, say the door is currently 1 1/2" thick and the indents are 3/8" deep, and you want to make the door 2" thick.  Would the indents remain 3/8" deep or go to 1/2" deep?

Comment: I want the indents to remain the same thickness so the mirror should be thicker

Comment: The question is really how to select faces/vertices regardless of subgrouping. If i can do that then I could use the move tool (I can do this if i explode the groups but that makes it hard to maintain)

Comment: It's been awhile since I used Sketchup, and I forget how to do exactly what you want, but it seems like there may be a workaround.  If the backside is flat, you could just work with that face to adjust thickness.  If it's double sided, split it in half front to back to create a flat face to work with in the middle.

Comment: Too much work :( Got a tip from the skechup forum to use a plugin, will check it out.. Its called FredoScale